# CMake warning: No Boost header defined

Tags: boost, cmake, header, warnings

I've installed Boost 1.64.0 on a Windows x64 machine.
Using CmakeLists.txt code below

```
set("BOOST_ROOT" "C:/local/boost_1_64_0/")
set("BOOST_INCLUDEDIR" "C:/local/boost_1_64_0/boost/")
set("BOOST_LIBRARYDIR" "C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.1")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

#find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem program)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS
system-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib
filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib
program_options-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I get three warnings, one for each library found:

```
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1566 (message):
No header defined for system-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1566 (message):
No header defined for filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1566 (message):
No header defined for program_options-vc141-mt-gd-1_64.lib; skipping header
check Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)
```

Any ideas how to make cmake find boost headers ?

Comment: Variables need to be set in CMake with `set(BOOST_ROOT "...")`. Note the missing quotes around the variable names. Your commented `find_package` call had the correct syntax. The current call is simply wrong. Finally add a `target_link_libraries(your_target_name ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` after your `add_executable` or `add_library` call.

Comment: The first find package call was commented because it returned the following errors:

`Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem
          boost_program`

I had to rename them explicitly, using the names from the 1.64.0 Boost version. The quotes around the path variables were removed.

Comment: Did you clear the CMakeCache.txt file after your changes? If not you should do and retry.

Comment: BTW, the third component library is called program_options, not program.

Comment: yes this is wrong for sure, I reverted my cmake configuration to the following line `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem program)` but I am still getting error `Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem
          boost_program_options`

Comment: I do clear the cache file every time I apply a change.

Answer (score 0):

to answer my question on the source of the problem.
Most likely the Boost installation was not done properly on the machine and the paths of the library were not generated as expected. I will check this again and redo my Boost installation, once more.